# How to generate mysql table for model in .net Core from linux?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, dbcontext

Developing on this platform `uname -a`:

```
Linux 5.8.0-63-generic #71-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 15:59:12 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and having setup mysql database:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

in Rider IDE, asp [core]:

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ItemsContext": "server=127.0.0.1;user=user;password=password;port=3306;database=test;"
  }
}
```

`WebApplication1/Models/Item.cs`:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models;

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Due { get; set; }
}
```

`WebApplication1/Data/ItemsContext.cs`:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data;

public class ItemsContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemsContext(DbContextOptions<ItemsContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

`WebApplication1/program.cs`:

```
using MySqlConnector;
using WebApplication1.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ 
    => new MySqlConnection(builder.Configuration["ItemsContext"]));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

If I now try to generate razor view for `Item` model, with this command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Item -dc ItemsContext -udl -outDir Pages/Items/ --referenceScriptLibraries
```

I got this error:

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...

Minimal hosting scenario!
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Item'
Unable to create an object of type 'ItemsContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
```

So it says `Unable to create an object of type 'ItemsContext'` and I am not sure, it is because of unable to connect to mysql, or what reason. But as everything else is set, how to fix this issue?

Comment: You are not supposed to call AddDbContext at some point of your config? What is the `MySqlConnection` class?

Comment: You´re conscious that these tutorials are not using entity framework, right? I suggest you read the proper EF docs on how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Your `ItemsContext` is inside the `ConnectionStrings` object, you can´t call it like the way you did, you have to pass the full path, like `ConnectionStrings:ItemsContext`, or better, use: `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ItemsContext")`.

Also, you are not registering the DbContext in your app in any moment, i recommend you to read the actual EF [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) on how to do this the proper way...

Comment: builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ItemsContext"): getting still rhe same error